# Github - Merging is blocked - The base branch requires all commits to be signed

Tags: git, github

Github is blocking the pull request from being merged, even though all the commits are verified.
Rule settings: 'Require signed commits' & 'Include administrators' are checked.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I saw [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55238987/7976758). Could it be a problem at Github?

Comment: Github added the cause in the message:
`Merge attempt failed  
Base branch requires signed commits. Rebase merges cannot be automatically signed by GitHub`

Answer (score 5):

It seems like this is a GitHub web interface only glitch.

The system can verify the signatures internally.

The trick to get through this is to use the "Command line instructions".

[image: Use the command line instructions]

I was able to merge the branch **without** turning off any checks.

[image]

Comment: Recreating a new PR worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this bug while attempting to merge a PR with a single signed commit into a protected base branch. It had received approval (one of the branch protection requirements, in addition to signature) so I was hoping to avoid needing to re-acquire that.

Closing the PR, then immediately re-opening it, enabled the merge button in this case.

Comment: Closing and re-opening the PR still shows: The base branch requires all commits to be signed.

Comment: @NoamManos are all the commits signed, that you’re trying to merge?

Comment: Yes, it was one commit and signed. Eventually I switched from SSH to GPG, and followed this answer to resolve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59351278/658497

Comment: That doesn’t make sense, what does ssh have to do with this? If that solution worked for you then it sounds like you used an email address (or gpg key) not associated with your Github account, and the branch protection functionality was working as intended.