# unverified commits in GitHub

Tags: git, github

In my GitHub Repository i have a branch , with some commits that are unverified,
is there any way to change them to verified ?

[image]

Answer (score 26):

Unverified means your signature is wrong.

This can be if you commit with the wrong E-Mail/Password, if you haven't uploaded the Signature on GitHub(on that account) or if you've uploaded it wrongly.

I think this is because you use the signature of your main account for committing with the other (maybe non-existing) account (maybe because you activated `commit.autosign`).

Your signature has to contain the E-Mail address of the account(that committed) and that account has to have the signature (with the E-Mail) uploaded on GitHub.

A commit from a non-existing user cannot be verified on GitHub too.

If you want to verify existing commits, you have to **overwrite** them.

## This involves a force push that forces other people to re-clone the repo. Because of that, you should not force push to master or any other long-lasting branches you may work together with other people

You can do this by re-committing it:

```
git rebase -i <commit before first problematic commit>
```

After this, your text editor will open up. Change every `pick` to `edit`.

After that you'll have to re-commit every commit with the following command:

```
git commit --author="<name> <<E-Mail(once in brackets, see example)>>" -S --amend --no-edit
git rebase --continue
```

In the end, you'll have to overwrite the remote by doing

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

This is better than `git push -f` but you should also be careful.

example of the commit command:

```
git commit --author="testuser <testuser@github.com>" -S --amend --no-edit
```

You also could do this using the `git filter-branch` command.

See [this](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/change-author-name-email) for details.

Comment: as you can see in my image, my new commits become "verified" after fixing my email address, how i can change my old commits from "unverified"  to "verified" ?

Comment: This was an excellent answer - thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Worked very well for me!

Answer (score 0):

Some times it is because of date/time problems
Fix it by executing this these shell commands....
Replace  with the last commit from where it is showing unverified.
I think starting of your last commit hash is df7326e (shown in the picture)

```
$ cd path/to/your/git
$ git filter-branch -f --commit-filter 'git commit-tree -S "$@";' -- --all
$ git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date <HASH>
```