# GitHub signed commits - The base branch requires all commits to be signed

Tags: git, github, signed

I'm enabling [Signed Commits](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.9/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/about-commit-signature-verification) on my GitHub repo and I've created a PR with only signed commits. However the merge is being blocked due to

> The base branch requires all commits to be signed

despite all the commits being signed.

[image: Merge is blocked]

[image: Verified Commits]

Googling I came across [Github - Merging is blocked - The base branch requires all commits to be signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235047/github-merging-is-blocked-the-base-branch-requires-all-commits-to-be-signed) and I've also tried

- Close and re-open the PR
- Re-create the PR
- Disable squashed commits
- Locally rebase and push to the PR

What else could be going on here?

Comment: Is the error happening when you create the PR, or when you try to complete it? If it's when you try to complete it, which merge strategy are you using for completion? (I'm guessing here that if you try to rebase when completing the PR it could fail for this reason, but a regular merge would work.)

Comment: @TTT that message shows up after the PR has been approved and the build succeeds. At that point it should be ready to merge, but the merge button is disabled. i.e. It's when I create the PR, and all the other checks have passed.